# Correct the update query for marking duplicate rows in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update

I'm trying to update a column with the value 1 where the following criteria match.

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT TBL.KEY, TBL.IS_DUPLICATE FROM MYTABLE AS TBL JOIN
(SELECT TBL1.KEY FROM MYTABLE AS TBL1 GROUP BY TBL1.KEY HAVING COUNT(TBL1.KEY)>1) SELECTION 
ON SELECTION.KEY = TBL.KEY ORDER BY TBL.KEY ASC) OuterSelection
SET OuterSelection.IS_DUPLICATE = 1;
```

Here is the error I'm getting when running this query.

**SQL Error [42807]: The target fullselect, view, typed table, materialized query table, range-clustered table, or staging table in the INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, MERGE, or TRUNCATE statement is a target for which the requested operation is not permitted.. SQLCODE=-150, SQLSTATE=42807, DRIVER=4.16.53**

Comment: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00150n.html
This may help

Comment: @ChristianCederquist If I don't use GROUP BY, HAVING then how I make selection only on duplicate rows?

Comment: I may have been wrong on what the problem was, as it mentions that it doesn't apply to subqueries

Comment: Yeah @ChristianCederquist I got your point but just asking not arguing that if is there any way to mark these duplicates? It will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Basically, the error is, that you have to UPDATE the table TBL, not the selection, specify the SET value and then have the conditions in the WHERE clause at the end.

Comment: @ChristianCederquist Yep! After your help, I'm trying this way but not successful yet. Lets see how far I can make with it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51052/discussion-between-christian-cederquist-and-superman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that the selection had to be matched in the WHERE clause, and the UPDATE should just specify the table. Here is the solution:

```
UPDATE TBL
SET IS_DUPLICATE=1
WHERE KEY IN (SELECT KEY
FROM TBL
GROUP BY KEY
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```